# How to handle lots of drawables

Tags: android, drawable

I am developing a game, where I use lots of drawables. The "drawable" catalog hold over 10MB memory ( about 900 of drawables ). At the beggining of each game level I am loading the array of drawables only the necessary drawables, so when I am drawing them I only refer to certain drawables. This reduce the amount of my drawables to about 300, but there are some cases when then can be even 900 drawables that are used. Even though when I readed drawables they use over 40 - 50MB of memory. I was trying to load them them during the game but this was useless, because the game slows incredible.

Ok. I forgot to add some code :P My game is base on LunarLancher, so code is nothing new for you.

```
class  GraphicView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{   
  class GraphicThread extends Thread
  {
    public GraphicThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context, Handlerhandler )
    {
      ...
      LoadPixmap(context);
      ...
    } 

    private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
      m_Pixmap[iIndex].setBounds( m_iX, m_iY, m_iX + WIDTH_I, m_iY + HEIGHT_I );
      m_Pixmap[iIndex].draw( canvas );
    }
  }

  private void LoadPixmap(  Context context  )
  { 
    int iID = 0;
    Resources res = context.getResources();

    for( int iIndex=0; iIndex< m_Objects.size(); ++iIndex )
    {
      if ( IsPixmapNeeded(m_Objects[iIndex]) )
      {
        continue;
      }

      iID = res.getIdentifier("pixmap"+i, "drawable", "com.my.package");
      if ( iID != 0 )
      {
        m_Pixmap[iIndex] = context.getResources().getDrawable(iID);
        m_Pixmap[iIndex] = new ScaleDrawable( m_Pixmap[iIndex], 0, WIDTH_I, HEIGHT_I).getDrawable();
      }
    }
    res = null;
    context = null;
  }

   m_Pixmap[]   =  new Drawable[ FRAMES ];
}
```

This code is only a sample that I have written right now, but I the idea is the same.

This

```
LoadPixmap(context);
```

method is called also when I update all variables, so I have chance to add/remove some drawable that I will need to use.

and this part of code

```
if ( IsPixmapNeeded(m_Objects[iIndex]) )
```

prevent me to loading drawables that are right now in m_Pixmap array.

My question, what is the right way to handle lots of drawables? My issue isn't the problem of my code, I rather would like to find some better way to handling lots of drawables.

Comment: So, for clarification. At the start of each level you generate and store upwards of 900 drawable objects in an array. You then have some sort of logic that determines what drawable objects in that array need to be drawn and then draw them to the screen? Are you using a loop that re-draws the screen every few milliseconds? Does it only redraw when some action is executed? `Can you provide code snippets`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a bitmap factory to load these bitmaps anywhere?

If so,

Make sure you take into account BitMap.recycle();

And also, make sure every phone has enough VM budget to allocate the memory for these images.

If you aren't using bitmapfactory then, it's kk.